# Hibernate 5.1 implementing UserType for Oracle SYS.XMLTYPE

Tags: hibernate, jpa, xmltype, hibernate-5.x

I am trying to store Oracle XMLTYPE data as JPA Entity in my java application. First I implemented UserType for xml field:

```
    public class FiledsListUserType implements UserType {

    private static JAXBContext jaxbContext;

    public Object nullSafeGet(final ResultSet resultSet, final String[] names, final SessionImplementor session, final Object owner) throws SQLException {
        XMLType xmlType = (XMLType) resultSet.getObject(names[0]);

        ...
```

But the problem is I get null in nullSafeGet `resultSet.getObject(names[0])`. I thought if happened because I used EntityManager instead of Session but now it doesn't seem that. Also I noticed that other fields are successfully obtained from Oracle. Here is my Entities:

```
@Entity
public class Application implements Serializable{
...
   @Type(type = "fieldsList")
   @Column(name = "XMLOTHERINFORMATION")
   private FieldsList xmlOtherInformation;
...


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "list")
public class FieldsList {

    @XmlElement(name = "Field")
    private List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<Field>();

...

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Field {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String id;
    @XmlElement
    private String fldCode;
...
```

As documentation said I registered my UserType as follows:

```
public class OracleXmlDialect extends Oracle10gDialect {

    public OracleXmlDialect() {
        registerColumnType(XMLType._SQL_TYPECODE, "XMLTYPE");
    }

    @Override
    public void contributeTypes(final TypeContributions typeContributions, final ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        super.contributeTypes(typeContributions, serviceRegistry);
        try {
            registerTypes(typeContributions);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void registerTypes(final TypeContributions typeContributions) throws JAXBException {
        typeContributions.contributeType(new FiledsListUserType(), "fieldsList");
    }
```

So what I missed?